# How much did McGonagall know about Snape?

Tags: harry-potter, severus-snape, character-motivation, minerva-mcgonagall

A follow-up question of [What did Professor McGonagall know about the Order of the Phoenix?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/63482/what-did-professor-mcgonagall-know-about-the-order-of-the-phoenix)

It seems that before the Battle of Hogwarts, McGonagall faced Snape in a brief battle. Snape escapes as a coward, as McGonagall shouted. Now did she know that Snape planned this? It seems to me that she doesn't know. In the books, only Harry and Dumbledore know that Snape is a double agent.

Comment: Is this a movie-only question?

Comment: Yes. But I would be more happy if you answer it in books and movies separately☺